# How to target/select div by class and class within that div

Tags: javascript, class, selectors-api

How do I select and target `.circle` within `.lallern hit-5`?

```
<div class="lallern hit-4">
    <div class="circle"></div>
</div>

<div class="lallern hit-5">
    <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

I tried with querySelectorAll but no luck

```
document.querySelectorAll("lallern.hit-5 .circle");
```

Answer (score 4):

small mistake

```
document.querySelectorAll(".lallern.hit-5 .circle");
```